# Как прикрутить React JS на многостраничный сайт?

Tags: reactjs

Есть платформа для создания интернет магазинов
Много страниц
В конструкторе есть поле для добавления html кода
Я смог добавить create-react-app приложение к магазину черерез github pages
Но я не понимаю, что мне делать дальше, как добавлять компоненты на конкретных страницах

Есть есть мысли как сделать исходя из того, что я описал выше или может вообще другой способ буду рад

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите использовать компоненты в динамически генерируемых страницах на вашей cms, для начала нужно подключить react, т.е. в вашем случае добавить в шапку сайта cdn - https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html
Можно для теста добавить cdn в редакторе кода html (при создании страницы). И вы сможете использовать react только на этой странице.

К сожалению, пользоваться компонентами скомпилированного create-react-app приложения которое находится на github pages не получится.